# Correct webapi routing setup for deserialising POST contents

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, xml-deserialization

I am trying to write a webapi method that reads the POST message contents and converts it into an object automatically. I know that there must be the underlying functionality in mvc to do this as you can see from this example:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Book value)

{
    try
    {
        using (SampleDbEntities entities = new SampleDbEntities())
        {
            Book foundBook = entities.Books.SingleOrDefault<book>(b => b.ID == id);
            foundBook.BookName = value.BookName;
            entities.SaveChanges();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now, in this example, the web api is nicely de-serialising the contents of the post packet and putting it into the incoming parameter *book*. How do I work with this? I have a the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage RequestMarkAdjustment([FromBody] MarkAdjustment value)
    {
        //work with the mark object
    }
```

I have have all the xml in my post packet:

```
<MarkAdjustment>
<PersonNo>123456</PersonNo>
<Date>2014-12-03T09:25:15</Date>
<StartPeriod>1</StartPeriod>
<EndPeriod>2</EndPeriod>
<ClassCode>CL883A</ClassCode>
<Reason>Some Reason</Reason>
</MarkAdjustment>
```

My request URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3485/api/Person/RequestMarkAdjustment/123456
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:3485
Content-Length: 448
```

The routing always makes it through to the method, but the mark object is *null* Do I have to change something in the routing? I see that the working example is part of the RESTful architecture but there must be some way to plumb into the nice de serialisation functionality it uses.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why would you have the id as a parameter in the POST? if you know the location of the resource it should be a PUT. Otherwise, your method should be something like 
public HttpResponseMessage RequestMarkAdjustment([FromBody] MarkAdjustment mark);

Comment: Cheers Martin. Updated the code to remove the id parameter and add the [FromBody] attribute. It is still coming through as null. This function exists in my person controller as an extra side function. Does it have to be one of the basic crud operations?

Comment: And you still have the same problem with the MarkAdjustment object being null?

Comment: Yep, still getting the problem

Comment: Okay, interesting. Where are you performing the POST from? Could you show the entirety of your request (with headers etc)?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using the older routing class, and not the newer routing Attributes? can you post the route that is being triggered here?

Comment: I am sending the POST request from fiddler. I have added the request and headers. the content length will not be accurate as I had to anonomise some data.

Comment: I have not added any of my own routes. It has thankfully worked out of the box for everything I have done so far. All I have done is *sent* data up until now. I did do one instance of reading XML from the body, but I did that the old fashioned way by reading it into an xml document etc.. This time I thought I would actually use propper de-serialisation! I have noticed some of this routing attribute stuff on forums and articles. I did not know it was the standard now. I'll look into it.

Comment: Now that you have removed the Id parameter from the action, you should remove it from your Url so you are calling http://localhost:3485/api/Person/RequestMarkAdjustment/ Also, as Thibault below has stated there is no mention of your content type, you will need to set that header too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the header of your HTTP request, it looks like you are omitting the `Content-Type`.
You have to set the `Content-Type` to **application/xml** in order to tell to the model binder which Media-Type Formatter it should use.

Besides, by default, **XmlMediaTypeFormatter** uses the **DataContractSerializer** class to perform serialization. Since you do not have any namespace set in your XML example you should use a **DataContractAttribute** on your model like so :

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class MarkAdjustment
{
  ...
}
```

If you prefer, you can configure the XmlMediaTypeFormatter to use the **XmlSerializer** instead of the DataContractSerializer. To do so, set the UseXmlSerializer property to true:

In the Register method of WebApiConfig:

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Comment: That's the chap! Thank you very much!